# Straight edge between clusters in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to have an edge between clusters in Graphviz where the edge does not affect the ranking.

This looks fine:

```
digraph {
  subgraph clusterX {
    A    
    B
  }

  subgraph clusterY {
    C
    D
  } 

  A -> B
  B -> C [constraint=false]
  C -> D
}
```

[image]

However when I add a label to the `C -> D` edge the `B -> C` edge tries to circumvent said label (which looks ugly).

```
digraph {
  subgraph clusterX {
    A    
    B
  }

  subgraph clusterY {
    C
    D
  } 

  A -> B
  B -> C [constraint=false]
  C -> D [label=yadda]
}
```

[image]

Any idea how I can keep the edge from `B` to `C` straight?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to add `splines=false` to the dot file - this forces the rendering of the edges to be straight lines:

```
digraph {
 splines=false;
 subgraph clusterX {
    A;
    B;
 }

 subgraph clusterY {
    C;
    D;
 } 

 A -> B;
 B -> C [constraint=false];
 C -> D [label=yadda];
}
```

Output:

[image: graphviz output]

Comment: Instead of edge that goes straight from first node to second node i got edge that is still curved, but is refracted instead of smooth :/

Answer (score 3):

You can use this version :

```
digraph G { 
  subgraph cluster_X {
    A [ pos = "0,1!" ]; 
    B [ pos = "0,0!" ];
  } 
  subgraph cluster_Y {
    C [ pos = "1,1!" ]; 
    D [ pos = "1,0!" ];
  } 
  A -> B
  B -> C[label="yadda"]
  C -> D;
}
```

Then you use neato (not dot)

```
neato -Tpng -oyadda.png yadda.dot
```

And the result is :

[image]

Comment: with neato I do not get the cluster boxes anymore. Right?

Comment: @towi, [yes](https://forum.graphviz.org/t/why-does-neato-not-support-cluster/680/2). Citate: `We should generate a warning. fdp has clusters and makes similar layouts but with different algorithms.`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `label` attribute, you can use the attributes [`xlabel`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/xlabel/) or [`headlbel`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/headlabel/) or [`taillabel`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/taillabel/).

- Result with `xlabel`:
  [image: label on an edge made with graphviz dot]
  Script:

  ```
  digraph {
      subgraph clusterX { A B }
      subgraph clusterY { C D } 
      A -> B
      B -> C [constraint=false]
      C -> D [xlabel=yadda]
  }
  ```
- Result with `headlabel`:
  [image: label on an edge made with graphviz dot]
  Script:

  ```
  digraph {
      subgraph clusterX { A B }
      subgraph clusterY { C D } 
      A -> B
      B -> C [constraint=false]
      C -> D [headlabel=yadda]
  }
  ```
- Result with `taillabel`:
  [image: label on an edge made with graphviz dot]
  Script:

  ```
  digraph {
      subgraph clusterX { A B }
      subgraph clusterY { C D } 
      A -> B
      B -> C [constraint=false]
      C -> D [taillabel=yadda]
  }
  ```