# How to force straight splines with Graphviz record

Tags: graphviz, dot

There are multiple questions e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006792/straight-edge-between-clusters-in-graphviz), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115870/creating-straight-edges-in-graphviz/12869546), and [here](https://forum.graphviz.org/t/force-straight-edges-above-through-a-node/741). Asking how to force straight edges for connectors in Graphviz (dot).

The answers include:

- `splines=line;`
- `splines=false;`
- compiling with neato
- and a [longer example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115870/creating-straight-edges-in-graphviz) that creates straight lines by creating invisible nodes.

(How) can I force straight connectors from the top of one record to another with this example without resorting to invisible nodes (if possible)?

```
digraph select {
    splines=line;
    // splines=false;
    node [shape=record];
    rec1 [label="<f0> left|<f1> middle|<f2> right"];
    rec1:f0:n -> rec1:f2:n;
}
```

Edit: a question was asked - how can the record have a connecting edge if it's one record and how can that not be straight?

A record can point at different parts of itself. The question is how to get that to be straight i.e. go out turn at a 90 degree angle, go, turn at a 90 degree angle, and connect?

i.e. not a curved edge:
[image: connector with curved edge]

Comment: Only one record involved.  How would a straight edge be visible?

Comment: The answer should be "splines=ortho" (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/splines/).  But in this case (both ports on same node) it fails miserably (try it).  "splines=polyline" also fails.  It is possible to post-process the curved splines to make 90 degree angles (I'd use GVPR), but that is probably more effort than you want.